# Visual Studio 2015 - debug parou de funcionar asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Quando eu passo o mouse sobre uma variável ao depurar um aplicativo C # no Visual, o mesmo trava e fica mostrando algumas mensagens. Estou executando o Visual Studio 2015 Community no Windows 8.1 de 64 bits. Alguém sabe o que pode impedi-los de mostrar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, já tentou reinstalar o VS?

Comment: Eu fiz de tudo, a única solução após ter reinstalado o VS, recuperado o Windows foi formatar tudo é instalar tudo de novo

Comment: Este problema já foi resolvido?

Comment: Solução: remover e instalar tudo de novo!